# Why doesn't my ubuntu host doesn't allow RMI calls from JMeter?

Tags: linux, networking, java, firewall, jmeter

i'm running a jmeter client on my ubuntu maschine. I try to start remote tests via RMI. The start works fine, but i don't get the results back.

---

> Start JMeter Server (rhel 6.5):

$HOME/jmeter/bin/jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.168.88.2

> Start JMeter Client (ubuntu 14.04):

$HOME/jmeter/bin/jmeter -java.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.88.2'

> Start JMeter Client (Windows 7):

c:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -java.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.113.47'

---

This error occures in the jmeter-server.log when i run the tests from host (ubuntu) and with a small change on my guest VM (windows7)

```
**Ubuntu**
ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) 
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;
**Windows7**
ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) 
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.113.47;
```

**Fact**: the IP of my guest VM (win7) will be transfered to the jmeter server, but my ubuntu host doesn't reach this point.

My IPTables look like this on my Ubuntu host:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
```

I guess that the firewall is blocking all the incoming RMI callbacks and some (ubuntu host) outgoing information.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: `iptables -L` shows the filter rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to deactivate all firewall rules. The RMI calls were blocked by the firewall.

Now I'll adjust the firewall and the testing can begin :)

Comment: That's great that it worked for you, but could you consider explaining *how* you did that so that someone else in your situation in future can also deactivate firewall rules blocking RMI? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading these articles - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-port-forwarding-set-up-load-testing-on-compute-engine/ and https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-controller---generators-communication for better understanding of communication between nodes in distributed mode.

The hostnames you are setting via *-Djava.rmi.server.hostname*, are they hostnames of the machines the instances is running on? I mean 10.168.88.2 is the hostname of the server and 192.168.88.2 is the hostname of your Ubuntu machine?

Also make sure you can *ping* from the server to the client, because server needs to connect to the client in order to send results.

If you cannot make direct access from server to client, use SSH tunneling (described thoroughly in the first article).

Hope this helps.